# How to generate yml config file using terraform

Tags: automation, yaml, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I want to generate yml config file using terraform can anyone pls help me?
suppose I want my config.yml file contents as

```
this is a line
this is 2nd line
```

how can I do that

Comment: Why do you need to create a yml file with terraform? What is your usecase?

Comment: How are you passing the data to encode  it in yaml config? the data is coming through stdin or from another source ?

Comment: @aashitvyas I have a variable.tf file which provides me variables with list of ip addresses
I also have a template file where I am running for loop to list ip addresses from my variables.tf.

In my main.tf, I used templatefile() function to use my template.tpl file and it's working fine
I wrote the code in <output> block.

Comment: Now the problem is I have multiple line output and the output format is heredoc with <<EOT printed out around the output.
I found a solution for that i.e to use -raw option with <terraform output command>
However, while using -raw option, we can't print every output all together. We have to mention each labels one by one to print in -raw format.
I was thinking if I can use only one 'value' key in output block which will contain both strings and templatefile() function.

Comment: I know my explaination is bit confusing, sorry for that
I am new to terraform so I tried my best to explain the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `yamlencode` function for making properly formatted yaml , but not files. You can find examples on how to use it [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/yamlencode.html).

Comment: I was thinking that too
however I just started learning terraform and I am confuse about blocks. I can't figure out in which block or how can I use yamelencode in my main.tf

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the output of [yamlencode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/yamlencode) as a variable in the [templatefile](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) function.
It's helpful to use the [indent](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/indent) function to ensure everything is shifted properly.

**Here is an example:**

Create an template yaml file in your repo and put a template-variable in it:
*yaml-file.tmpl*

```
myYaml:
  ${yaml_code}
```

Then call the templatefile function with the `yaml_code` template variable set to your custom yaml code:

```
locals {
    yaml_file = templatefile("${path.module}/yaml-file.tmpl",
      {
        yaml_code = indent(2, yamlencode(["this is a line", "this is 2nd line"]))
      }
    )
}
```

The file will now have the following yaml code. You can use the `yaml_file` local-variable in your terraform code.

```
myYaml:
  - "this is a line"
  - "this is 2nd line"
```